# VBA Sort shift delete 2 cells if specific cell is empty

Tags: vba, sorting, shift

I need some help with a VBA code. I am trying to shift delete 2 cells in 2 columns A and B, if cell in column B is empty. I need to repeat this action 10 times.

I have a VBA code that does this with a filter on blanks in Column B. It works fine on a small dataset, however, since my datasets are very big and the actions need to be repeated 10 times, it takes a lot of time.

```
Sub del()
  For i = 1 To 10
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
    Range("b:b" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Range("a:a" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

 Next i

End Sub
```

I was thinking that instead of filtering, to:
-sort column B to get all blanks at the end
-select from the first blank cell until the end of the row (for both A and B columns)
- delete selected
- repeat this action for 10 times

I tried a few things, but I cannot get a proper code for this.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank,
Daniela

Comment: your narrative is about shift/delete _"2 cells in 2 columns"_ while your code looks like you're trying  to delete entire columns. Furthermore it cannot be your _"code works fine"_ since `Range("b:b" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` would throw an error (and `Range("a:a"...)` as well). Please clarify and also tell us what's your real goal you're trying to achive by means of filtering and delete/shifting ten times and  maybe there comes out a better solution.